# How to get multiple columns in Crosstab

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I would like a cross table from the following table.

[image]

The cross table should look like this

[image]

A pivot table does not seem to solve the problem, because only one column can be used at a time. But in our case we are dealing with 4 different columns. (payment, month, year and free of charge)
I solved the problem by splitting these 4 columns into four different pivot tables, using temporary tables and finally reassembling the obtained data. But this is very complicated, long and confusing, in short not very nice... 
The years and months should be shown in ascending form, exactly as you can see in the cross table above.

I have been looking for a solution for quite a while but I can't find the same problem anywhere. 
If someone would give me a short, elegant solution I would be very grateful.

Under http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7216f/2 you can see the problem definition.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rank records by date in a subquery with `row_number()`, and then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    ClientId,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Payment end) Payment1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Payment end) Payment2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then Payment end) Payment3,
    max(case when rn = 1 then [Month] end) Month1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then [Month] end) Month2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then [Month] end) Month3,
    max(case when rn = 1 then [Year] end) Year1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then [Year] end) Year2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then [Year] end) Year3,
    max(case when rn = 1 then FreeOfCharge end) FreeOfCharge1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then FreeOfCharge end) FreeOfCharge2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then FreeOfCharge end) FreeOfCharge3
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by ClientId order by [Year], [Month]) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by ClientId
```

Comment: Also good solution that works. Still have to decide which solution I will use :)
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table with itself a few times, as in:

```
with p as (
  select
    *, row_number() over(partition by clientid order by year, month) as n
  from Payment
)
select
  p1.clientid,
  p1.payment, p2.payment, p3.payment,
  p1.month, p2.month, p3.month,
  p1.year, p2.year, p3.year,
  p1.freeofcharge, p2.freeofcharge, p3.freeofcharge
from p p1
left join p p2 on p2.clientid = p1.clientid and p2.n = 2
left join p p3 on p3.clientid = p1.clientid and p3.n = 3
where p1.n = 1
```

See [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7216f/5).

Comment: I got my "short, elegant" solution I "dreamed" of :) Good thing you and Stackoverflow are here!
Thank you very much and happy new year.

P.S. at the beginning has to be a semicolon and then it is perfect.

Comment: With this solution I could not insert the result into a temporary table. So I used the solution from GMB because with his solution it is easy to insert the result into a temporary table.

Comment: No worries. If you ever needed to combine a CTE with an insert, just add the `INSERT` clause just before the main (last) `SELECT`.